How can I get all Set-Cookie headers using Flask
Somewhat complicated situation. I have a ubuntu server acting as a VPN server for a number of remote nodes.
This server is hosting a Flask web server to display connected information about each node. The nodes themselves are also hosting a web server (actually hosted on a router).
I am trying to implement http proxying so that a user can view the web page on the router, via the main website. I've had some success with this (login page is displayed correctly and allows a POSTed login form to be authenticated) however I've run into an issue where the router site (which is written by the router manufacturer Teltonika) is returning multiple Set-Cookie headers. I can see these are being returned by watching the network trace in the browser. They look like this:
'Set-Cookie':"sysauth=<auth_string_redacted>; path=/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=<token_redacted>; HttpOnly; Secure"
'Set-Cookie':"session=<long_session_string_redacted>; HttpOnly; Path=/"

These cookies contain the data required for the requests to be authorised.
When I try and retrieve these headers from both the Flask.Response.headers dict or the Flask.Response.raw.headers.get_all function only the first header is ever shown. The second one containing the session is completely omitted and seemingly irretrievable.
Output of resp.raw.headers:
HTTPHeaderDict({
    'Connection': 'close', 
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 
    'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 
    'Strict-Transport-Security': 
    'max-age=31536000;, max-age=31536000;, max-age=31536000;, max-age=31536000;', 
    'Set-Cookie': 'sysauth=<redacted>; path=/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=<redacted>; HttpOnly; Secure', 
    'Content-Type': 'text/html', 
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
    'Expires': '0'
})

This means I can't get the site to log me in properly as I can only set the cookies from the first header (crucially missing the session value).
My question is; how can I get the value of both of these headers using Flask? Or, why aren't the headers being correctly combined by Flask into a single Set-Cookie header?
I would really hate to have to rewrite this whole http proxy using a different library.

Set-Cookie is in response headers, not request headers.

You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. So I don't see how you could have multiple Set-Cookie elements in the header dictionary.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125660/how-does-pythons-requests-treat-multiple-cookies-in-a-header use .cookies instead of .headers

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Barmar thanks for the response; I am getting the header value from the response not request, typoed it. I know the header can't appear twice in the dict but I would've assumed Flask would combine the two headers into a single entry in the dict but it doesn't seem to be doing. Unfortunately the cookies passed back in .cookies don't contain the session or token, only the sysauth has been set.
